# iOS APIS - 'Reference'

Tags: ios

In iOS, we have CGContextRef, CGFontRef and such. What do 'Ref' indicate here? Are they refernces to objects of type CGContext, CGFont ? I do not understand this particular concept. Where can I look for the explanation of this concept?
Any help appreiated,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, CGContextRef, CGFontRef and such are pointer types (typedefs) to plain C structures, *not* to Objective-C objects, and they are coming from older C frameworks of Mac OS X. See [CGContext reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000950), [CGFont reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGFont/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000953), [Core Foundation Design Concepts](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/CFDesignConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000122i)  and [Memory Management Programming Guide for Core Foundation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/CFMemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000127i). Because those *Ref objects are ``toll-free bridged'' with the Objective-C Cocoa framework, you can substitute them for Cocoa objects in function arguments, and vice versa ([3](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/CFDesignConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000122i)). They have their own rules for memory management ([4](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/CFMemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000127i)).  I myself got a first brief but mostly sufficient explanation of those Core Foundation objects and frameworks by watching the [Stanford iPhone Programming class videos](http://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/iphone-application-development/id384233225) (see also the [class' site](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/)).

Hope I gave you some pointers to start with.

Answer (score 1):

Cmd+Click on the desired type:

```
/* The type used to represent a CoreGraphics font. */
typedef struct CGFont *CGFontRef;
```

There is a struct `CGFont`. **typedef** keyword makes alias `CGFontRef` for this struct. 'Ref' indicates that it's a pointer.